# Comparar dos array y mostrar el contenido de ambos en php

Tags: php, mysql, php7

Amigos estoy en un pequeño problema que es de parte de mi lógica que no e logrado dar solución, es un problema pequeño pero ya llevo un rato probando de todo y no e podido solucionar, verán tengo dos lista que me trae de base de datos, una contiene unos 11 elementos y otra apenas unos 5, la lista mas pequeña tiene los elementos seleccionados de la mas grande, la cuestión es mostrar de la lista mas grande los elementos seleccionados y los que no estan.

Tengo esto hasta el momento

```
<?php if (!empty($lista_categoria)): ?>
        <h4>CATEGORIA INSTANCIA</h4>
        <?php for ($i = 0; $i < 11; $i++): ?>
              <?php foreach($cat_post as $V): ?>
                    <?php if($V->ID == $lista_categoria[$i]->ID): ?>
                          <div class="checkbox">
                                <label>
                                     <input type="checkbox" name="catg[]" value="<?php echo $lista_categoria[$i]->ID ?>" checked="checked">
                                    <?php echo $lista_categoria[$i]->CAT ?>
                               </label>
                           </div>
                     <?php else: ?>
                         <div class="checkbox">
                              <label>
                                   <input type="checkbox" name="catg[]" value="<?php echo $lista_categoria[$i]->ID ?>">
                                  <?php echo $lista_categoria[$i]->CAT ?>
                              </label>
                          </div>
                    <?php endif; ?>
             <?php endforeach; ?>
       <?php endfor;?>
<?php endif;?>
```

La cuestion es que de esta forma me repite la cantidad de categoría en base a la cantidad de la lista mas pequeña, es decir si la lista mas pequeña tiene unos 5 elementos las categoría se repiten 5 veces

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como podría solucionar este pequeño inconveniente.

Comment: Por favor lee [ask], edita y coloca el código como texto y no como imagen pues para las personas que puedan ayudarte les será difícil tratar de replicar tu ejercicio

Answer (score 1):

Podrías conseguir lo que necesitas por medio de dos funciones de **PHP** muy útiles a la hora de trabajar con `array`.

Supongamos que **A** es tu lista con todos los elementos y que **B** es la lista menor de elementos con la que deseamos cruzarla.

> `array_intersect ( array $array1 , array $array2 [, array $... ] ) : array`
>
> `array_intersect()` retorna un array que contiene todos los valores de
>   **array1** que están presentes en todos los argumentos. Observe que las
>   claves se mantienen.

Lo que significa, en nuestro caso, que te retorna todos los elementos de **A** que también estén presentes en **B**. Resumiendo, nos retorna los elementos seleccionados que buscas.

> `array_diff ( array $array1 , array $array2 [, array $... ] ) : array`
>
> `array_diff()` compara **array1** con uno o más arrays y devuelve los
>   valores de **array1** que no estén presentes en ninguno de los otros
>   arrays.

En nuestro caso nos devuelve todos los valores de **A** que no estén en **B**. O lo que es lo mismo, nos devuelve los elementos no seleccionados.

**Ejemplo:**

```
$frutas_caja = array('platano', 'manzana', 'pera', 'fresa', 'sandía', 'mora');
$frutas_sobre = array('platano', 'sandía');

$seleccionados = array_intersect($frutas_caja, $frutas_sobre);
$no_seleccionados = array_diff($frutas_caja, $frutas_sobre);

echo 'Seleccionados: ';
var_dump($seleccionados);
echo '<br>';
echo 'No seleccionados: ';
var_dump($no_seleccionados);
```

**Referencias:** [array_intersect](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-intersect.php), [array_diff()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-diff.php)